# manipulating csv with ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV from which I've removed the irrelevant data.
Now I need to split "Name and surname" into 2 columns by space but ignoring a 3rd column in case there are 3 names, then invert the order of the columns "Name and surname" and "Phone" (phone first) and then put them into a file ignoring the headers. I've never actually learned Ruby but I've played with Python 10 years ago. Can you help me? This is what I was able to do until now:

E.g.

```
require 'csv'

csv_table = CSV.read(ARGV[0], :headers => true)

keep = ["Name and surname", "Phone", "Email"]

new_csv_table = csv_table.by_col!.delete_if do |column_name,column_values|
  !keep.include? column_name
end

new_csv_table.to_csv
```

Comment: Do you mean that the entries in the column “Name and surname” are two words separated by a space? Fields are comma-separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by creating a CSV file.

```
str =<<~END
Name and surname,Phone,Email
John Doe,250-256-3145,John@Doe.com
Marsha Magpie,250-256-3154,Marsha@Magpie.com
END

File.write('t_in.csv', str)
  #=> 109
```

Initially, let's read the file, add two columns, `"Name"` and `"Surname"`, and optionally delete the column, `"Name and surname"`, without regard to column order.

First read the file into a `CSV::Table` object.

```
require 'csv'
```

```
tbl = CSV.read('t_in.csv', headers: true)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

Add the new columns.

```
tbl.each do |row|
  row["Name"], row["Surname"] = row["Name and surname"].split
end
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

Note that if `row["Name and surname"]` had equaled `“John Paul Jones”`, we would have obtained `row["Name"] #=> “John”` and `row["Surname"] #=> “Paul”`.

If the column `"Name and surname"` is no longer required we can delete it.

```
tbl.delete("Name and surname")
  #=> ["John Doe", "Marsha Magpie"]
```

Write `tbl` to a new CSV file.

```
CSV.open('t_out.csv', "w") do |csv|
  csv << tbl.headers
  tbl.each { |row| csv << row }
end
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

Let's see what was written.

```
puts File.read('t_out.csv')
```

displays

```
Phone,Email,Name,Surname
250-256-3145,John@Doe.com,John,Doe
250-256-3154,Marsha@Magpie.com,Marsha,Magpie
```

Now let's rearrange the order of the columns.

```
header_order = ["Phone", "Name", "Surname", "Email"]
```

```
CSV.open('t_out.csv', "w") do |csv|
  csv << header_order
  tbl.each { |row| csv << header_order.map { |header| row[header] } }
end
```

```
puts File.read('t_out.csv')
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

displays

```
Phone,Name,Surname,Email
250-256-3145,John,Doe,John@Doe.com
250-256-3154,Marsha,Magpie,Marsha@Magpie.com
```

Comment: you ignored this bit: "I need to split "Name and surname" into 2 columns by space but ignoring a 3rd column in case there are 3 names".

Comment: @Adobe, assuming my understanding of that requirement is correct, that's covered. Suppose `x, y = "John Paul Jones".split`, then `x #=> "John"; y #=> "Paul"`.